# How to assert if a Completable has been subscribed/completed (RxJava2)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm having trouble identifying if a `Completable` has been subscribed to in my tests, for example:

```
interface IWebApi {
    Observable<Data> download();
}

interface IDataRepository {
    Completable insert(Data data);
}

class SyncService {

    IWebApi webApi;
    IDataRepository repository;

    public SyncService(IWebApi webApi, IDataRepository repository) {
        this.webApi = webApi;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Completable sync() {
        return webApi.download()
            .flatMapCompletable((Data data) -> { repository.insert(data) })
    }
}
```

And then in my tests:

```
@Test
public void syncTest() {
    Data data = new Data();
    IDataRepository repository = mock (IDataRepository.class);
    IWebApi webApi = mock (IWebApi.class);

    given(webApi.download()).willReturn(Observable.just(data));
    given(repository.insert(data)).willReturn(Completable.complete());

    TestObserver<Void> observer = new TestObserver<Void>();
    SyncService service = new SyncService(webApi, repository);
    service.sync()
            .subscribe(observer);

    observer.assertComplete();
    verify(repository).insert(data);
}
```

This test will pass. But I Could rewrite the sync method without using `flatMapCompletable` like this:

```
    public Completable sync() {
        return webApi.download()
            .doOnNext((Data data) -> { repository.insert(data) })
            .ignoreElements();
    }
```

Then my tests would pass but code would not work because even thought I've called the insert method, I've not called `subscribe()` in it.

How should I proceed about this?

P.S I am new to RxJava so if I am not using the best practices I would love to know :)

**Update**

Fixed the mistake of not calling `.ingnoreElements()` pointed by Maxim Ostrovidov

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the `flatMapCompletable` way.

Comment: @akarnokd Yeah, I think it's a lot preferable actually, but I believe the test should fail if someone changes it for some reason to one of the methods that do not subscribe to the observable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `test()` operator for convinience:

```
SyncService service = new SyncService(webApi, repository);
TestObserver observer = service.sync().test();
```

> But I Could rewrite the sync method without using flatMapCompletable like this:

```
public Completable sync() {
    return webApi.download()
        .doOnNext((Data data) -> { repository.insert(data) })
}
```

This won't compile because `doOnNext` is used only to invoke actions on items, not changing the stream return type. In your case method is expecting `Completable` but actually it will be `Observable<Data>`.

Even if you force change the eventual stream type:

```
public Completable sync() {
    return webApi.download()
        .doOnNext((Data data) -> { repository.insert(data) })
        .ignoreElements(); //converts to Completable
}
```

`repository.insert(data)` will not be invoked because `doOnNext` is not subscribing to anything you passed and not returning anything:

```
//under the hood of lambdas
.doOnNext(new Consumer<Data>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Data data) throws Exception {

    }
})
```

Your initial code is the best for what you want to achieve:

```
public Completable sync() {
    return webApi.download()
        .flatMapCompletable((Data data) -> { repository.insert(data) })
}
```

`flatMapCompletable` subscribes to passed `Completable` using items emitted by `Observable`:

```
.flatMapCompletable(new Function<Data, CompletableSource>() {
    @Override
    public CompletableSource apply(Data data) throws Exception {
        return repository.insert(data);
    }
})
```

**Edit**

To test the fact of `repository.insert` subscription you can use another `TestObserver` and `Completable` with applied `doOnSubscribe`:

```
TestObserver repositoryInsertObserver = TestObserver.create();
Completable insertCompletable = Completable.complete()
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> repositoryInsertObserver.onSubscribe(d));

//pass completable to your mock
given(repository.insert(data)).willReturn(insertCompletable);

//and verify that subscription took place
repositoryInsertObserver.assertSubscribed();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I forgot to call `ignoreElements`, already updated. I didn't know about the test operator, that's nice!! I agree that the `flatMapCompletable` is the best approach but I would like to ensure that the test breaks if someone makes the mistake of thinking that `doOnNext` would subscribe. Any solution you know?

Comment: Thanks!! That was exactly what I was looking for!!